# Neater Way to Set One of Two Variables to a Certain Value Based on a Boolean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've noticed that I use this pattern a lot in my C# code. (It's within a Unity script, if it matters.)

```
if (someBoolean) {
     firstVar = 10;
} else {
     secondVar = 10;
}
```

My question is as simple as can be--is there a way to make this pattern take up less space than the five lines it does? Perhaps even make it inline? I thought ternary operators might do it, like so...

```
(someBoolean ? firstVar : secondVar) = 10;
```

...But it quickly became apparent ternary operators in C# don't work like that.

I also considered creating some sort of global function in a static class that I could simply pass the appropriate variable to, but it's the pattern that is frequently repeated, not necessarily the operation. So the function method wouldn't work for where I've repeated this pattern elsewhere, with different operations, like so...

```
if (anotherBoolean) {
     thirdVar += exampleVar;
} else {
     fourthVar += exampleVar;
}
```

Of course, I could just do this...

```
if (someBoolean) { firstVar = 10; } else { secondVar = 10; }
```

...But that's kind of icky, isn't it? Either way, I'd appreciate any advice you could provide. Many thanks.

Comment: If you were in C or C++, you could obfuscate that code with a ternary returning the address of one of the two variables, which you could dereference and use as an lvalue. As for C#, just write the if/else. It's not "icky", it's readable.

Comment: You can even get rid of the braces In your last example.

Comment: `(someBoolean ? (Action<int>)(n => firstVar = n) : n => secondVar = n)(10);` (Note: this suggestion is for entertainment purposes only).

Comment: I see... well, if if/else is the way to go, I suppose I should just swallow it. Ta.

Comment: Gah! I felt inspired by Sach's answer and went to make an answer to post. I should have retracted my close vote. Oh well, I'll share what I made here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2qJJp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Destructuring assignment (C# 7)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-deconstruction) to make it into single statement:

```
(firstVar, secondVar) = someBoolean ? (10, secondVar) : (firstVar, 10);
```

Whether it is more expressive than simple `if` is up to debate, but it gives you single statement at least. Can be good option if the rest of the project actively uses "destructing" and new C# 7+ features.

Unlike [suggestion to use helper function with `ref` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527910/477420) destructing can be used for arrays, lists and properties:

```
(list[0], list[1]) = someBoolean  ? (list[0], 10) : (10, list[1]);
(x.SomeProp, x.OtherProp) = someBoolean  ? (x.SomeProp, 10) : (10, x.OtherProp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use if/else. You--by which I mean I--are/am overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a frequent occurrence, you can make use of extension methods as well.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var firstVar = 1;
        var secondVar = 2;

        true.SetValue(ref firstVar, ref secondVar);
        false.SetValue(ref secondVar, ref secondVar);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public static class BoolExtensions
{
    public static void SetValue(this bool bVal, ref int first, ref int second)
    {
        if (bVal)
            first = 10;
        else
            second = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: I gotta be honest, I really dont like this solution

Comment: @maccettura fair enough. I too would just simply write `if-else` but OP doesn't seem to like them. And this works. :)

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't work in my case. As mentioned, I've repeated the pattern, but the operations I perform are often entirely different. There's setting, adding, reversing, concatenating, sub-stringing, etc., etc.

This would definitely work if I was repeating the pattern _and_ operation though. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @NicolasKarayakaylar you could write a set of different extension methods for each operation. But I think you're really fretting over a non-issue. `if/else` statements are perfectly readable and not too much work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'll stick with if/else. Thank you!